# HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: php, html, lua

So, I'm trying to make a promotion bot for Roblox using Webservices.

Here is what code I have:

```html
<?php
$group_id         = $_GET['groupId'];
$new_role_set_id  = $_GET['newRoleSetId'];
$target_user_id   = $_GET['targetUserId'];


$login_user       = 'username=RPIRankBot&password=NoYou';
$file_path_rs     = 'rs.txt';
$file_path_token  = 'token.txt';
$current_rs       = file_get_contents($file_path_rs);
$current_token    = file_get_contents($file_path_token);


function getRS()
{
 global $login_user, $file_path_rs;

 $get_cookies = curl_init('https://www.roblox.com/newlogin');
 curl_setopt_array($get_cookies,
  array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
   CURLOPT_POST => true,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Length: " . strlen($login_user)),
   //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $login_user
  )
 );

 $rs = (preg_match('/(\.ROBLOSECURITY=.*?);/', curl_exec($get_cookies), $matches) ? $matches[1] : '');
 file_put_contents($file_path_rs, $rs, true);
 curl_close($get_cookies);

 return $rs;
}


function changeRank($rs, $token) 
{
 global $group_id, $new_role_set_id, $target_user_id, $file_path_token;
 
 $promote_user = curl_init("http://www.roblox.com/groups/api/change-member-rank?groupId=$group_id&newRoleSetId=$new_role_set_id&targetUserId=$target_user_id");
 curl_setopt_array($promote_user,
  array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_POST => true,
   CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Cookie: $rs", "X-CSRF-TOKEN: $token")
  )
 );

 $resp = curl_exec($promote_user);
 $resp_header_size = curl_getinfo($promote_user, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
 $resp_header = substr($resp, 0, $resp_header_size);
 $resp_body = substr($resp, $resp_header_size);

 if (preg_match('/GuestData/', $resp_header)) {
 
  $resp_body = changeRank( getRS(), $token );
 } else if (preg_match('/Token Validation Failed/', $resp_header)) {

  $new_token = (preg_match('/X-CSRF-TOKEN: (\S+)/', $resp_header, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '');
  file_put_contents($file_path_token, $new_token, true);
  $resp_body = changeRank( $rs, $new_token );
 }

 curl_close($promote_user);

 return $resp_body;
}


echo changeRank($current_rs, $current_token);
```

This is giving me the HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

I've looked all around about this error, all of the scripts had the stuff to do with MySQL which wasn't what I was looking for. I know you have to supply a content header to the server, but I am confused as to how to do it.

Help would be greatly appreciated.